# Java Deflater Output

Tags: java, compression, output

In Java, I have created a class called Writer that extends 
It is initialized with the followin, where bos is a ByteOutputStream:

```
this.internalWriter = new Writer(bos, Manager.defaultSize, new      Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true));
```

When later I call

```
bos.writeTo(System.out);
```

Everything seems to work okay. But I noticed if I check out what bos is actually outputting by converting it to a byte array, it is always outputting these three bytes at the end of anything, and I don't know why that would occur...any ideas? This is causing problems in my compression algorithm...

Those confusing three bytes are as follows:

```
[-27,2,0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Writer`s in java treat everything like a `String` so what you're seeing would be `\r\n\0`, which is a DOS newline sequence, followed by a string terminator.